# How do you make the application get to read the 1st letter of the 2nd word

Tags: java, string, char

The question that my teacher gave me is : Create a Group Assignment that prompts the user for his or her name and then displays a group assignment. The group assignment depends on the FIRST LETTER OF THE STUDENT'S LAST NAME. Last names beginning with A through I are assigned to group 1, J through S are assigned to group 2 and T through Z are assigned to group 3.

example output:
Enter you first and last name: Janus Smith
You are assigned to group 2.

I don't know the code to get the first letter of the second word and if they are still code error please do fix it. Tnx.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    
    System.out.println("Enter your first and last name: ");
    name = scan.nextLine();
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
        char ch = name.charAt(0);
        
        if(ch >= 'A' || ch >= 'a' || ch <= 'I' || ch <= 'i'){
            System.out.println("You are assigned to group 1.");
        }
        else if (ch >= 'J' || ch >= 'j' || ch <= 'S' || ch <= 's'){
            System.out.println("You are assigned to group 2.");
        }
        else if (ch >= 'T' || ch >= 't' || ch <= 'Z' || ch <= 'z'){
            System.out.println("You are assigned to group 3.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's so nice that you are ordering us to fix your program. You can use String#split() to find the second word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the whitespace-separated strings and extract the parts like this:

```
String name = "First Second";
String[] parts = name.split(" ");
// extract the second string from the 0-indexed array
String second = parts[1];
// extract the first character from the second string
char ch = second.charAt(0);

// no need to loop for a single name check

if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'I' || ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'i'){
    System.out.println("You are assigned to group 1.");
}
else if (ch >= 'J' && ch <= 'S' || ch >= 'j' && ch <= 's'){
    System.out.println("You are assigned to group 2.");
}
else if (ch >= 'T' && ch <= 'Z' || ch >= 't' && ch <= 'z'){
    System.out.println("You are assigned to group 3.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
}
```

Comment: You don't need a loop here.

Comment: My bad, I assumed this comparison is done for a list of names.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#split` to split the name by space to get two parts.

```
String[] parts = name.split(" ");
```

`parts[0]` has the first name and `parts[1]` has the last name.

Get the first char of the last name as

```
char ch = parts[1].charAt(0);
```

---

Also your conditions are wrong. You must use `&&` to check if the char is between a range.

```
 if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'I' || ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'i')
```

To simplify the conditions, you can convert the character to either lower or upper case and check for one set of range.

```
char ch = Character.toUpperCase(parts[1].charAt(0));

if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'I') {...}
else if (ch >= 'J' && ch <= 'S') {...}
else {...}
```